# Pressing two on-screen buttons at the same time, with the same touch - Android Unity Event-Triggers

Tags: unity, input, touch

OK so I have this code working and the methods are being called at the times I'd expected (ie. when the mouse hovers over the button and stops hovering over it)

But when I test it on an Android device, it is not possible to press both buttons at once. The only button that gets pressed is the one where the touch-down happened.

```
 public class EventHandlerThrust : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
 {
 public static EventHandlerThrust instanceOf;

 [HideInInspector] public bool isButtonPressed = false;

 void Start()
 {
     instanceOf = this;

 }

 public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     isButtonPressed = true;
     Debug.Log("OnPointerEnter Interfaceyyyy called.");
 }

 public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     isButtonPressed = false;
     Debug.Log("OnPointerExit Interfaceyyyy called.");
 }
 }
```

So is it possible to allow the user to press both buttons by holding his thumb over both at the same time, using the Event Trigger System? Or do I have to implement some other kind of Input system?

Comment: I've researched this for many weeks, I really shocked that there isn't a way to do it already built into Unity. I mean honestly its fairly important functionality to be able to press both buttons at once if you ask me. I've tried Raycasting // Event Triggers // OnPointerEnter // OnPointerDown ... always same results. But I had minor success with Rects around the touch area. But it still doesnt work seemlessly and you have to be careful with the placement of the onscreen buttons.